# Will clearing an already empty vector lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior, std

What happens if I `clear` a `vector` which was already cleared before? 
I tried it out in Visual Studio and it did not lead to any run-time errors. But I'm hunting for a possible cause to an exception (below)  And wanted to know if this could be the reason?

```
*** glibc detected *** process.out: double free or corruption (out): 0x01a0b588 ***
```

Updating code:

```
bool myclass::Sort(SortType enSortOption)
{

  bool bRet = TRUE;


  m_oVecOfIntsOrig.clear();
  m_oVecOfIntsSorted.clear();

  for(int i = 0;i<m_oList.listsize();i++)
  {
    m_oVecOfIntsOrig.push_back(i);
  }
  m_oVecOfIntsSorted = m_oVecOfIntsOrig; 
  //Just sort the indices     
  switch(enSortOption)
  {
  case Alpha:
    { 
      t_SortStructAlpha sSortAlpha(this);
      sort( m_oVecOfIntsSorted.begin(), m_oVecOfIntsSorted.end(), sSortAlpha );        
    }
    break;
  case Dist:
    {        
      t_SortStructDist sSortDist(this);
      sort( m_oVecOfIntsSorted.begin(), m_oVecOfIntsSorted.end(), sSortDist );
    }
    break;
  case none:  
    {

      //Nothing to do
      return TRUE;
    }
    break;  
  default:
    {
      bRet = FALSE;

    }
    break;
  }

  //Update the list based on sorted index vector
  ListElem oSortedListElements;
  //this clear function simply clears all the 7 constituent vectors. 
  oSortedListElements.vClear();
  if(TRUE == bGetSortedList(oSortedListElements))
  {
    //If successfully copied to temp object, then update member variable
    //m_oList is what I'm intending to display
    m_oList.vClear();
    m_oList = oSortedListElements;
  }
  else
  {
    //copy failed
    bRet = FALSE;

  }
  return bRet;
}


bool myclass::bGetSortedList(ListElem& oSortedListElements)
{

  bool bRet = TRUE;

  //Creating object from beginning, so clear old contents if any
  oSortedListElements.vClear();
  /* Sort done. Now update the list based on new indices*/
  for(int u16Index = 0; u16Index<m_oVecOfIntsSorted.size(); u16Index++)
  {
    if(
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec1.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec2.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec3.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec4.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec5.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec6.size())
      ||
      (m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index) >= m_oListConstituents.oVec7.size())
      )
    {
      //out of bounds check
      return FALSE;
    }
    //m_oListConstituents contains overall list
    oSortedListElements.oVec1.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec1.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec2.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec2.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec3.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec3.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec4.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec4.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec5.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec5.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec6.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec6.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));
    oSortedListElements.oVec7.push_back(m_oListConstituents.oVec7.at(m_oVecOfIntsSorted.at(u16Index)));     

  }

  return bRet;

}
```

Comment: What are you storing inside the vector? raw pointers? or classes with pointer members? Check if you are following the Rule of Three for your class. If raw pointers, check where you are transferring ownership.

Comment: I am using about 7 vectors.They are of the following types: String, user-defined enum type, double, integer, STL pair

Comment: @pavanvkulkarni: You mean, C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `clear` method twice in a row should be fine.  Your error looks like you are freeing something which was already freed.  This can happen because you called `free` twice on the same object or possibly put an object in your vector which was then deleted.  Calling `clear` on your vector would then cause that error (this is a problem because `clear` calls the destructor on any objects contained in the vector).

**Edit:**

`at` returns a reference so deleting something set to a value returned from an `at` might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks !! I think this is what my code does at the moment. I'll go ahead and correct it.

Comment: On second look, I could not notice any apparent errors. There were no pointers being dealt with in these vectors (I corrected my comment in OP). The vectors simply contained objects which are one among these: standard datatype, a simple user defined enum type and STL pair. For your mentioned situation to occur, I must delete an object (which I should have dynamically allocated) and then called clear() on the vector. But I don't see that happening... Any other hints would be very much helpful..! Thanks again

Comment: Without seeing some code it's hard to tell... *cough* code *cough*

Comment: I have updated the code which was flagged as suspect by the exception.

Comment: @ mydogisbox Both 'm_oVecOfIntsOrig' and 'm_oVecOfIntsSorted' are in fact vectors of the list indices before and after sort. They basically hold integers. So instead of actually sorting the list up and down based on alphabetical order etc, this code first sorts the list indices alone and then moves the list elements later in the function 'bGetSortedList()' . You mentioned "This deletes all the objects in m_oList and the next time you try to delete any of the above you get the error." But I think ' m_oVecOfIntsOrig' / 'm_oVecOfIntsSorted' are independant of 'm_oList'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3863/discussion-between-pavanvkulkarni-and-mydogisbox)

Answer (score 7):

If what you did amounts to

```
v.clear();
v.clear();
```

then no, there's no UB: one of the postconditions of `v.clear()` is that `v.size() == 0`, so the second call to `clear` should be a no-op.